# Report state to GOOGLE, The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: google-smart-home

When I test to report smart home devices state to google, I get the following error:

```
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"}
```

I follow this guide https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state#service-account-key to get Service Account Key。

```
HttpEntity entity = httpRequest("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/homegraph", jwt, params, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

This is my code to get token.

```
HttpEntity entity = httpRequest("https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:reportStateAndNotification", token, params, "application/json");
```

This is my code to report status.

I want to know if the token is invalid or what is wrong.

In addition, Does this have to do with agentUserId.

```
{"requestId": "123ABC","agentUserId": "user-123","payload": {
"devices": {
  "states": {
    "light-123": {
      "on": true
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your `agentUserId` in your JSON request - you can retrieve this by using the [OAuth Playground tool](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state?hl=en#expandable-2).

The [Account Linking guide](https://medium.com/google-developers/aog-protips-account-linking-verification-for-smart-home-1fc5a9273971) also explains how to use this tool for verifying you have properly configured all of your auth tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Now,I try other way,but I got another bad request.

```
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided."}, iss: securam-report-state@securam-smart.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I change to user **GoogleCredentials**

```
GoogleCredentials creds;
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("/usr/local/cloud_config/securam-smart-88f8bf5c2792.json");
    creds = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
    creds.createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/homegraph");
    creds.refreshIfExpired();
    AccessToken token = creds.getAccessToken();
    return token.getTokenValue();
```